# Bower install issue

Tags: command-line, bower, bower-install

When adding packages with Bower, I'm getting this error message every time I don't know how to resolve the issue?

I was trying to load font awesome or bower install by doing

```
$ bower install --save font-awesome
$ bower install
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/configstore/index.js:54
                throw err;
                ^
    Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/brandonpowell/.config/configstore/bower-github.json'
    You don't have access to this file.

        at Error (native)
        at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:640:18)
        at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:508:33)
        at Object.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/configstore/index.js:35:26)
        at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/configstore/index.js:28:44)
        at readCachedConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/config.js:19:23)
        at defaultConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/config.js:11:12)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/index.js:16:32)
        at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check permissions of that file:

```
ls -laF ~/.config/configstore/bower-github.json
```

You've probably run `bower` as `root` user before. It should be enough to run:

```
sudo chown brandonpowell ~/.config/configstore/bower-github.json
```

Comment: Its say something about an illegal group name

Comment: Yep, sorry. I was just guessing primary group name. But there's no need to change the group. I've updated the answer.